# How to find approximately triangles in image by using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have this image:
[image: Original image]

And I want to find isosceles right triangles like this:
[image: Triangle found]

How can I do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: give line segment detector or other edge detection a chance as a first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to blur your image, convert in to gray scale and apply differnet threshold to your image. Next step is to find and arrange your contours and maybe filter them out with limiting sizes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('triangle.png')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
values = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for i in values:
    ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_image,i,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    area = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    for j in range(1, len(area)):
        contour = area[j]
        size = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if 10 < float(size) < 140000:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

Result:

[image]

Note:

Transformation to different color space and applying different threshold could improve the resut.

Comment: I like this approach +1 !!

Comment: You could include shape approximation to remove the square contour

Comment: @Jeru Luke: Thats a great idea!

Comment: @Jeru Luke: I once used in an image inspection the variable for checking circularity of contour...I think the triangles should return different values as rectangles

Answer (score 1):

*(Take note that I manually cropped out the graph portion from your image before proceeding)*

**Steps:**

1. Converted the image to HSV color space and extracted the **hue** channel.

[image]

2. Performed Otsu threshold on the **hue** channel.

[image]

3. Labelled contours that closely resembled the shape of a triangle.

   - First, find the perimeter of each and every contour.
   - Use the perimeter to approximate a closed curve around the contour with a few number of lines possible. This technique is called the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).
   - Check if the number of curves enclosing the contour is 3. If it is draw it.

I was able to obtain the following:

[image]