# How to find the angle of a triangle from an image of a triangle

Tags: python, opencv

I have this following image, from which I need to find the angle theta (highlighted by red). The triangles are always orientated in the same direction having two sides of equal length. How can I do it in Python? I know I can do it by just drawing lines along the sides of the triangle for each specific case, but I need something automated in order to run a search over 2,000,000 such images.

[image]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You need to do your research on image processing and line detection.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. But I have also seen posts like these, which gave me the idea that it is okay to ask this in here. Maybe some one can at least point me at the right direction (refer to a function or share a similar example).  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833477/how-to-find-approximately-triangles-in-image-by-using-opencv

Comment: Yes, there are more inappropriate posts than we have active users to remove them.
That doesn't cause them to be suitable for the site charter.

Comment: See my attempt at an answer below. I've provided a link to get you started...it's actually a relatively simple problem once you learn what tools to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question with numerous possible answers. I can give you a some tips on how to start to tackle this problem, but there is no dead-simple out of the box answer.

You will want to make use of openCV. The general outline of the steps you will have to take is as follows:

**Threshold:** to turn it into a binary image.

**Erosion/dilation:** *Maybe* needed to connect all of the discrete points into a congruous blob/feature.

**FindContours:** To find the boundary of your shape

Once you have your contours, you'll have some actual numbers to work with and you can perform geometric analysis on them to determine the characteristics of your triangle. You can also use some of the following built-in functions to help do that as well, but this is by no means an exhaustive list of options:

**ConvexHull**: Will basically draw straight lines connecting the maximum edges of the feature.
**ApproxPolyDP**: Can also be used to find polygons

The [OpenCV python tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) are really good and easy to follow. Follow those and you should be able to figure this out pretty easily!